# MySQL istallation problem on Ubuntu 16.04 (my.cnf public ip problem)

Tags: mysql, 16.04, ip

I follow these [instructions](https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/install-mysql-on-ubuntu-14-04) to install mysql in Ubuntu 14.04 and it works great. But I make a clean installation of Ubuntu 16.04 and make the same steps to install MySQL and I have problems.

The `my.cnf` file is clean. I replace the content for `my.cnf` file from theubuntu 14.04 installation, restart the service and it doesn't work.

At this point I can't allow access to MySQL on a public IP by modifying the `bind-address` parameter in `/etc/my.cnf`.

Answer (score 17):

The configuration file name and directory change in Ubuntu 16.04 
The new file and location here:

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

You can edit this using:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

OR

```
sudo vi /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

I find this solution here:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-linux-16-04/

Answer (score 8):

The configuration file name and directory changed in Ubuntu 16.04 when compared to Ubuntu 14.04. The new file is located here:

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

You can edit it using:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

Answer (score 0):

When we try to edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf file we will see something like this:
[image]

As the file is protected so we can edit

sudo vi /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf file.